# Getting Parcelable Error in android in release build only

Tags: android, flutterwave

I am using [flutterwave](https://developer.flutterwave.com/docs/android) in my android project. It works perfectly find in `debug build` but when I use `release build` then app crashes whenever I call flutterwave activity to start

I am getting this error:

> Unable to find generated Parcelable class for
>   com.flutterwave.raveandroid.l, verify that your class is configured
>   properly and that the Parcelable class
>   com.flutterwave.raveandroid.l$$Parcelable is generated by Parceler.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add these lines in Proguard rules to make it work for Release Build

```
-keepclasseswithmembers public class com.flutterwave.raveandroid.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.flutterwave.raveandroid.card.CardFragment
```